# LinkedIn grab logic

Tags: rest, facebook-opengraph, linkedin-api

Can anyone explain me how does linkedIn grabber works? I share a message via REST API and under message title some additional content is shown. I concluded that linkedin grabs this content from my site(because when I tested posting on local server - shared message is pretty clear as LinkedIn couldn't grab anything from there), but how does it works?

OpenGraph tags are set to correct values, but extra content in message is even not from home page. It looks for me like it grabs random piece of my site and posts it. Also picture does not match one in OG tag.

I'll be appreciate for any help for getting this issue more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by passing straight description and image link in request to API